# String is not assignable to onMouseEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this logic wherein I have a conditional that if it is true it will assign a value on `onMouseLeave` otherwise none. Though I do understand the error is there any way to do it?

```
<li
class="some_class"
onMouseLeave={meta.hover ? onMouseLeaveEventFunc : ''}
>
```

The error I encounter:

```
Type 'string | ((event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void)' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, strings are not a valid value as an event handler.

Instead of an empty string (when `meta.hover` is `false`), you could pass `undefined`

```
onMouseLeave={meta.hover ? onMouseLeaveEventFunc : undefined}
```

Comment: Now I know `undefined` can be assigned as value. Thanks :)